# Java 2D Int Array Index out of bounds

Tags: java

I have a 2d int array. I'm trying to do board[6][5] but it's giving me an error, index out of bounds. I know its index is 0 but I need 6 x 7 board. This is what I have so far:

```
board = new int[][] { 
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, 
            { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        };
```

I need it in 42 pieces, so is it possible? If so, please help me

Comment: Java arrays are 0 -indexed and two dimensional calls the higher level of nesting first. Take another look at your code (I'm not the downvoter, btw)

Comment: @k_g I really don't see anything wrong.

Comment: How big is the first level of nesting in your array?

Comment: You currently have a 6x7 array.  remove a column and add a row to make it a 7x6 array which `board[6][5]` would then give you the last variable or keep it the same and index it using `board[5][6]`

Comment: @k_g 6 levels(without counting 0)

Comment: @chancea What if i want to do `board[6][6]`, thats the highest I want it to go. But with 42 integers

Comment: The first level of nesting is how many 1D arrays you have. This may be a little confusing, but the way you have it written, Java accesses `y` first then `x`.

Comment: You should add an extra row of zeroes, which will give you a `7x7`

Comment: @k_g But I also need it to print the integers. This is what I have for converting to string `for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
      int[] sub = board[i];
      for (int x = 0; x < sub.length; x++) {
       System.out.print(sub[x] + " ");
       sb.append(sub[x]).append(",");
      }
      System.out.println();
  }`

Comment: If you want to go with `board [6][6]` then do what @k_g said but you will have 49 integers.  You can choose to ignore 7 of them but you cant just not have them

Answer (score 1):

If you want to initialize a 2D array full of 0's you don't need to list them.

```
int[][] board = new int[6][7];
```

will do the trick. Since you haven't included anything yet, every element of your board will be 0.

However you cant call the element board[6][7] since your board has 42 pieces and each row starts at element 0 so the last element is

```
System.out.println(board[5][6]);
```

Hope this helps